# Set TinyMCE Editor Param after Initialized 

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to set the `readonly` parameter in tinyMCE to `true` after tinyMCE has been initalized. I am trying to use this with wordpress to disable the postEditor if the post has already been published. I found some sources claiming that you can call:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand(
    'mceSetAttribute',
    false,
    {name:'readonly',value:true}
);
```

but I have been having no luck with that and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An easier way to set this is `tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.readonly = true;`
But the problem here is that the readonly setting affects the way tinymce gets initialized.
So setting it after tinymce is initialized won't have a big impact.

What you can do to prevent users from editing content in your editor is to set the contenteditable attribute of the editors iframe body to false:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

Comment: the problem I'm experiencing with this solution @Thariama, is that I keep getting that `tinyMCE.activeEditor is null` . Any idea why? I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051093/tinymce-options

Comment: "tinyMCE.activeEditor is null" - happens when the tinymce editor is still not initialized. it is best practice to change the contenteditable attribute onInit of the editor

Comment: the error I get is after tinyMCE was initialized, that's the weird part. What I'm trying to do is that on a checked check box, set the tinyMCE to readonly.

Comment: I guess noone has clicked into the editor till then (that's when the var activeEditor gets set). What do you get when logging "console.log(tinymce.editors[0])" to console? I guess you will find the editor there. If you now the editors id you should replace activeEditor with get('your_editor_id')

Comment: `console.log(tinyMCE.editors[0]);` results in `undefined` and `tinyMCE.get('intro').setAttribute('contenteditable', false);` results in `undefined` also

Comment: if tinyMCE.editors[0] is undefined - there cannot be a valid editor instance at all. can you see any editor?

Comment: that's the trick... the editor actually works, is initialized http://pastebin.com/JEn2fyE6

Comment: in this case this might be a scope problem. is the var "tinymce" defined?

Comment: could you please create a tinymcefiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) - makes it easier to show you a solution

Comment: I managed to solve it, check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051093/tinymce-options/11455431#11455431

Comment: your solution is equal to tinymce.get('intro').setAttribute('contenteditable', false); - the jQuery approch will create some overhead, but jQuery will do the same thing on the base

Comment: This option still allows the selected text to be replaced