# tinyMCE options

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How can I toggle the `readonly` state in an initialized tinyMCE container?

Whilst the tinyMCE is initialised in a common javascript file, the option I want to change is specific to the logic of an individual page, and changes based on user's input via a checkbox.

This are some of the things I tried and all resulted in failure:
http://pastebin.com/JEn2fyE6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just managed to do it this way:

Having the `textarea` set with id `intro` I do this

```
if($('.disabled_check').is(':checked')) {
    $('#intro_ifr').contents().find('body').attr('contenteditable', false);
}
```

Comment: this is the only answer. if you have a targeted id.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to set this option http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:readonly
after the init. according to this thread: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=15488 it can not be done according to the folks of the tinymce forum.

This S.O. answer seems to work: [Set TinyMCE Editor Param after Initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946391/set-tinymce-editor-param-after-initialized)

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

If it does not, this topic has **a workaround**:
http://forum.morfik.com/posts/21058 create two instances of tinymce one readonly, one normal and only display the desired one.

Comment: I keep getting this error: `tinyMCE.activeEditor is null`. I load tinymce library `tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js` and initialize it in the common file `inyMCE.init({ ... });`

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code

`setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
                tinymce.editors[i].getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
            };
    },1000);`

Comment: Maybe not answered the question but worked for me on a `undefined tnymce` issue! Thanks!

Comment: it is not working on tinyMCE 3_5.8 version if there is any of the solution for the 3.5.8 version then Please share.

Answer (score 0):

You may set this setting after init using

`tinymce.get('my_editor_id').settings.readonly = false;`

But this won't influence the editor behaviour in the way you desire because the relevant part were processed while initialization.

The working approch here is what JP Hellemons already stated.